# Moderator Pro Tem Annoucement

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed.

[image: Evpok]
[image: F'x]
[image: Gilles]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections in several weeks.**
Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

---

Durant la phase de bêta nous avons besoin de membres du site dont la tâche est de guider la communauté dans sa construction et la dans la gestion du site. Nous choisissons pour cela quelques membres dans chaque communauté pour assumer le rôle de modérateurs temporaires. Vous pourrez trouver plus de détails sur ce système ici : [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

J'ai l'honneur de vous présenter les modérateurs temporaires pour FL&U, qui ont accepté généreusement de donner leur temps et leur aide pour s'assurer que la communauté puisse mener à bien ces tâches.

[image: Evpok]
[image: F'x]
[image: Gilles]

Nous voulons que ce site soit un énorme succès et ces membres sont les légendes vivantes dont nous devons tous nous inspirer¹. Accueillez-les chaleureusement pour récompenser leur labeur et le temps qu'ils consacrent au site.

#### Ai-je oublié certaines personnes ?

Quasi-certainement. Il y a d'autres membres particulièrement actifs et méritants. Si j'ai oublié quelqu'un, ce n'est *en aucune manière* de la malveillance. Dans l'idéal, les modérateurs sont choisis par la communauté. En conséquence **des élections auront lieu d'ici quelques semaines**. Enfin et surtout, soyez respectueux et compréhensifs envers vos modérateurs temporaires. Ils sont volontaires et apprennent en même temps que tous les autres.

—
<sup>1. bien que réflétant précisément la vérité, cette phrase a peut-être été sujette à une légère sur-interprétation de la part des traducteurs.</sup>

Comment: +1 pour la note de bas de page

Comment: Thumbs up all round. I was just about to retract my self-nomination. I realise I just don't have enough time.

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations to our moderators.

Answer (score 3):

Just wondering, how do we start a rebellion? I search on meta SO but didn't find anything.

<sup><sub><sup>It should be obvious, but more often then not it appears it isn't, so there: *I am joking.* Congrats to all 3!</sup></sub></sup>

Comment: On [metase], they're kind of lost in the noise of useful posts. Try [meta.programmers.se].

Answer (score 2):

Félicitations ! Et prenez bien soin de ce bébé qui vole ;-)

Comment: Pardon ; mélange de métaphores.

Comment: Je trouve que tu n'y vas pas avec le dos de la mer morte.