# 2020 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

French Language's [second moderator election](https://french.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the three new moderators are:

[image: Reyedy] [image: Tsundoku] [image: Luke Sawczak]

They'll be your first elected moderators since you lost your "beta" label last year—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Let's also take a moment to thank [the previous team who've served you as pro-tems](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/202/6994) while your site was still in beta.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5750172010151936/0).

Answer (score 7):

Congratulations to our new mods! You three seem to be very motivated and full of great ideas, which is certainly a nice change of pace from my tired self. I am very happy to have you as successors! Have fun in there :-)

Comment: Bon travail … ( litote :-)

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations to my new "colleagues" Tsundoku and Luke Sawczak! And many thanks to every voter who trusted me for this position, I will do my best to be a fair and good moderator.

I also say a big thank you to Evpok and the other 2 pro-tems moderators who did an awesome job building this site alongside the active members from back then, and making the job easier for everyone afterwards. You guys can be proud of yourselves, and we will do everything we can to live up to it.

Now, let's the work begin!

Answer (score 3):

Congrats to the new moderators !

As a quiting moderator, I would like to say a thanks you to @Evpok for his times to moderate FL. Thanks for all your time and input.

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations to the new moderators.
Many thanks to the previous ones.

Answer (score 3):

Congrats to you! Hope you will enjoy your new mission. Welcome to SE's moderators family and long live French.SE!