# I am quitting from my role as a Moderator / Je démissionne de mon poste de modérateur

Tags: discussion, moderation

*(French below)*

Hi everyone!

As you may know, [I was elected as a moderator for French SE](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/795/2020-community-moderator-election-results) a little less than two years ago. As a French language enthusiast, I wanted to step up and increase my contribution to a community that I admired. It has been a very rewarding experience, and I am proud to have helped as much as I could.

That said, I am delighted to announce that I will become a father in mid-June! As you can imagine, this wonderful arrival will also be time-consuming. And therefore, **I am stepping down from my moderator role for French SE**. I think this is the safest approach to a period of my life that will be totally dedicated to my baby, and it would be selfish of me to remain as a wholly inactive moderator.

I have learned a lot about the community and about myself in these (almost) two years of moderation, one of which being that this role is not fit for me: moderating quickly became a chore, and my work-life balance never allowed me to fully get involved in the community development (rather than only cleaning up and removing comments). I believe there is a lot to be accomplished by someone more active and dedicated. We are a small but strong group that can be developed in many ways.

That is also why, in mid-May, **a moderator election will take place** to designate the next member of the team! Staff from StackExchange will get in touch very soon with a dedicated Meta post. As for myself, I will leave my "job" as soon as my successor is officially elected.

I would like to thank the whole community for this experience, including my fellow moderators Tsundoku and Luke. I remain a French SE member and I will try to keep coming here as regularly as possible.

Thanks for reading and have a nice weekend!

---

Bonjour à toutes et tous !

Comme vous le savez peut-être, [j'ai été élu au poste de modérateur de French SE](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/795/2020-community-moderator-election-results) il y a un peu moins de deux ans. En tant qu'amateur de la langue française, j'ai voulu augmenter ma contribution à une communauté qui la rend plus accessible à tous. Cette expérience a été très enrichissante, et je suis fier d'avoir aidé autant que je le pouvais.

Ceci étant dit, je suis ravi de vous annoncer que je vais devenir papa en juin ! Comme vous pouvez l'imaginer, cette merveilleuse arrivée sera aussi chronophage. Par conséquent, **je quitte mon rôle de modérateur de French SE**. Je pense que c'est l'approche la plus prudente pour une période de ma vie qui sera totalement dédiée à mon bébé, et il serait égoïste de ma part de rester en tant que modérateur complètement inactif.

J'ai appris beaucoup de choses sur la communauté et sur moi-même dans ces (presque) deux ans de modération, en particulier le fait que ce rôle n'est pas fait pour moi : modérer est rapidement devenu une corvée, et mon équilibre travail/vie personnelle ne m'a jamais permis de m'impliquer totalement dans le développement de la communauté (plutôt que seulement faire le ménage et supprimer des commentaires). Je pense qu'il y a beaucoup de choses à accomplir pour quelqu'un de plus actif et dédié à la tâche. Nous sommes un groupe petit mais fort, qui peut être développé de plein de façons différentes.

C'est aussi pour cela qu'à la mi-mai, **une élection d'un modérateur aura lieu** pour désigner le prochain membre de l'équipe! Un membre du staff de StackExchange vous tiendra au courant très bientôt via un post dédié sur Meta. Quant à moi, je quitterai mon rôle dès que mon successeur sera officiellement élu.

Je souhaiterais remercier la communauté pour cette expérience, en particulier mes collègues modérateurs Tsundoku et Luke. Je reste un membre de French SE et j'essaierai de continuer à venir ici aussi régulièrement que possible.

Merci pour votre lecture et passez un bon week-end !

Comment: Congratulations on the **baby** and thank you for helping us! :) :) – 
Lambie

Comment: Thank you for the kind words!

Comment: +1 pour le petit +1, félicitations !

Comment: @Reyedy Détrompe-toi, tu auras plein de nuits blanches pendant lesquelles tu chercheras une occupation pendant le biberon ou les pleurs.

Comment: Pas sûr que je serai d'humeur à supprimer des commentaires ! :D

Answer (score 8):

J'ai mis +1 pour te remercier du message, pas par enthousiame pour ton départ (comme modérateur) !

---

Félicitations ! Certainement un gage d'un futur que d'avoir des enfants aujourd'hui, et ce sont de bonnes nouvelles qui apportent certainement espoir et confiance dans l'avenir ! Profites-bien de ces moments d'émerveillement et de vie et bonne chance !

Merci aussi pour ton soutien et ton travail comme modérateur (et on voudrait toujours en faire plus, autrement ; sauf qu'on a mis l'épaule à la roue afin d'aider la communauté et on s'en souviendra), un travail qui n'est pas toujours de tout repos ! Tu auras certainement l'occasion de te reposer davantage à la naissance de ton enfant ;-). Et qui sait peut-être qu'un jour il lira ce que tu viens d'écrire ici...

Salut !

Comment: _J'ai mis +1 pour te remercier du message_ Pareil.

Comment: Merci à vous deux. :)